# Loop using GO TO

Tags: cobol

I need to write a "for loop" in COBOL without using the 'PERFORM ... THRU ...' structure. My idea is to add a paragraph that I can jump back to once certain conditions are met. Here is what I came up with:

```
       PROGRAM-BEGIN.
       PAR-A.
       IF I <= 10 THEN
           SET J TO 1
           PAR-B.
               IF J <= 10 THEN
                   DISPLAY ARRAY(I,J)
                   SET J UP BY 1
                   GO TO PAR-B
               END-IF.
           SET I UP BY 1
           GO TO PAR-A
       END-IF.
       PROGRAM-DONE.
```

Clearly this doesn't work because writing in this way will incur a syntax error. Can anyone help me on this? I can only use `IF` and `GO TO`.

Comment: it is go to par-b in the middle of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you'd need with your existing structure. You've not shown the initialisation of `I`, but you'll need one. You've attempted to avoid an explicit termination condition/GO TO,

```
   PROGRAM-BEGIN.
       SET I TO 1
   PAR-A.
       IF I <= 10 THEN
           SET J TO 1
       ELSE
           GO TO PROGRAM-DONE
       END-IF
       .
   PAR-B.
       IF J <= 10 THEN
           DISPLAY ARRAY(I,J)
           SET J UP BY 1
           GO TO PAR-B
       END-IF
       SET I UP BY 1
       GO TO PAR-A
       .
   PROGRAM-DONE.
```

Note the use of the full-stops/periods. You should adopt that for your code, you'll have fewer troubles.

That comma is also trying to disguise itself as a full-stop/period/mark on the screen, and why even include it if you are jamming everything up against each other:

```
DISPLAY ARRAY ( I J )
```

There, isn't that nicer?

From the start, work on your names. Use descriptive names. I and J are just plain dumb, and in some wonderful situations you will even confuse them with the number 1.

```
       SET first-level-index 
           second-level-index       TO 1
       .
   output-results.
       IF second-level-index 
           NOT GREATER THAN 10
            DISPLAY 
                    ">"
                    the-data
                     ( first-level-index 
                       second-level-index )
                    "<"
            SET second-level-index  UP BY 1
            GO                      TO output-results
       END-IF
       IF first-level-index 
           NOT GREATER THAN 10
            SET second-level-index  TO 1
            SET first-level-index   UP BY 1
            GO                      TO output-results
       END-IF
       .
```

Or

```
   set-up-for-loop.
       SET first-level-index        TO 1
       .
   outer-loop.
       SET second-level-index       TO 1
       .
   inner-loop.
       IF second-level-index 
           NOT GREATER THAN 10
            DISPLAY 
                    ">"
                    the-data
                     ( first-level-index 
                       second-level-index )
                    "<"
            SET second-level-index  UP BY 1
            GO                      TO inner-loop
       END-IF
       IF first-level-index 
           NOT GREATER THAN 10
            SET first-level-index   UP BY 1
            GO                      TO outer-loop
       END-IF
       .
```

You'd give those paragrpah-names descibing the actual task.

Be aware that comparing indexes (your I and J) to literals requires some twists and turns for the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the syntax error caused by putting a paragraph name inside
the if, you can use the GOTO to move the PARB paragraph out of the first IF statement:

```
   PROGRAM-BEGIN.
   PAR-A.
   IF I <= 10 THEN
       SET J TO 1
       GOTO PAR-B
   END-IF

   PAR-B.
   IF J <= 10 THEN
      DISPLAY ARRAY(I,J)
      SET J UP BY 1
      GO TO PAR-B
   END-IF.
   SET I UP BY 1
   GO TO PAR-A

   PROGRAM-DONE.
```

Comment: Big. Fat. Loop. Two missing full-stops/periods. Why `GOTO PAR-B` (should be `GO TO...`) when PAR-B immediately follows the `IF`? No initial value for `I`, so don't expect it to even work then.